# How are Ground truth provided to each Pyramid map in RetinaNet or YOLOv3 Paper? How is the mapping of Feature Pyramids done to Ground Truth

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition, yolo

SO the [YOLO V3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.02767.pdf) and [RetinaNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002) both uses the Feature pyramids which look something like this:[image]
(except `b` and `e` which have one output)

I'm just confuse how the predictions and training is done?
Do we have to give **EACH** feature map a different `Y label`? IF yes, how is that possible? We need to have `N` different ground truth in my opinion. (Also ther'll be 3 different losses I think?)

If not, then how are these done at once?

There is a lot of confusion on these networks because I am not able to get my head around **How are y-labels provided, trained and predicted in YOLOv3 and RetinaNet** . Everything will make sense about loss, multioutputs and all if I know this one thing.

Comment: great question man, in short they do a heck of a complicated things to map boxes to anchors and then to tensors. Moreover each of the different approaches use a different strategy to map anchors, so the answer to your question is not short.

Comment: Long would do too ;)